# Как проскролить плавно страницу вниз до опреденнного элемента?

Tags: jquery

Проискал некоторые исходники - не работали. Это надо сделать на jQuery. Скролинг вверх я знаю, вот мне надо вниз и до определенного элемента, лучше с демо, чтоб посмотреть.

Comment: [http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) - такое подойдет?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky жаль что там не я задал этот вопрос, миллион просмотров...жесть =)

Comment: Здорово, что все же задали здесь!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да, почти 3 десятка тысяч врать не будут.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Создаете элемент до которого нужно скролить и запоминаете его id:

```
<div id="myDiv">content</div>
```

Далее создаете ссылку или кнопку с указанием id элемента куда скролить:

```
<a href="#myDiv">click me</a>
```

И собственно скрипт для скролинга:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        var elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
        var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
        if ($.browser.safari) {
            $('body').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1100); //1100 - скорость
        } else {
            $('html').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1100);
        }
        return false; 
    });
});
```

В данном скрипте работает прокрутка, как вверх, так и вниз.

UPD: добавлен полный пример страницы

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        var elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
        var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
        if ($.browser.safari) {
            $('body').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1100); //1100 - скорость прокрутки
        } else {
            $('html').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1100);
        }
        return false; 
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#botDiv">scroll down</a>
<div id="topDiv">div</div>

CONTENT

<a href="#topDiv">scroll up</a>
<div id="botDiv">div</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Предоставьте демо посмотреть, где скорлится до определенного элемента, а то когда я этот код тестил, у меня ничего не скорлило.

Comment: Демо предоставить не могу - следуйте описанным мной шагам и за считанные секунды сделаете рабочее демо. У меня данный код работает во всех браузерах. Могу лишь привести полный код рабочей страницы, если вам нужно.

Comment: давайте=...

Comment: Обновил ответ. Только в моем примере данный скрипт "вешается" на все ссылки на странице - вам нужно будет изменить селектор при переносе на реальный сайт.

Answer (score 3):

Допустим у тебя есть кнопка вверху экрана

```
<div class="email-button">
        <a href="#" class="button" >
            <i class="letter"></i>
        </a>
</div>
```

Дальше тебе нужен JQuery

```
$(".button").click(function(){
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("header").height()+ 7200 },"slow");

return false;});
```

В этом случае отбивка будет от моего **header**. Высоту в 7200 подбираешь сам.