# Прокрутка до определенного элемента в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, прокрутка

Если таблица, где каждая строка имеет свой id
так же есть ряд элементов  с ссылками содержащими id -

```
href ='"#"+id'
```

При нажатии на элемент таблица скролится к элементу строки таблицы.
Использую я для этого такой скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.a').click(function () {
        var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top}, 500);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

И у меня 2 проблемы:

1. Скрипт срабатывает 1 раз(закидывает в адресную строку #id), и больше при нажатии ничего не происходит.
2. Скрипт работает не плавно, а мгновенно (все файлы js подключены и обновлены, всё остальное работает)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73455/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Visman, ну я так и сделал. но работает с проблемами

Comment: все потому, что ссылка это элемент _а_, а ты добавляешь обработчик для элементов с классом _а_. Скорее всего, тебе надо просто убрать точку: `$('.a')` -> `$('a')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так обычно решаю (без проверки, а по фильтру+`data`):

```js
$('.link').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var link = $(this).attr('href');

  var dir = link.replace(/#/, ''),
      section = $('.section').filter('[data-section="' + dir + '"]'),
      pos = section.offset().top;

  
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000);
});
```

```css
.section  {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  
<a href="#item-1" class="link">item-1</a>
<a href="#item-2" class="link">item-2</a>
<a href="#item-3" class="link">item-3</a>
  
  <div class="section" data-section="item-1">1</div>
  <div class="section" data-section="item-2">2</div>
  <div class="section" data-section="item-3">3</div>
```

С таблицей:

```js
$('.link').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var link = $(this).attr('href');

  var dir = link.replace(/#/, ''),
      section = $('tr').filter('[data-section="' + dir + '"]'),
      pos = section.offset().top;

  
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000);
});
```

```css
tr  {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  

<a href="#item-1" class="link">item-1</a>
<a href="#item-2" class="link">item-2</a>
<a href="#item-3" class="link">item-3</a>
  
<table>
  <tr data-section="item-1">
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
   <tr data-section="item-2">
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
   <tr data-section="item-3">
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Вариант с таблицей и  до середины ячейки:

```js
$('.link').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var link = $(this).attr('href');

  var dir = link.replace(/#/, ''),
      section = $('tr').filter('[data-section="' + dir + '"]'),
      pos = section.offset().top +section.height()/2;
  
  
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 1000);
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr  {
  height: 500px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  

<a href="#item-1" class="link">item-1</a>
<a href="#item-2" class="link">item-2</a>
<a href="#item-3" class="link">item-3</a>
  
<table>
  <tr data-section="item-1">
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
   <tr data-section="item-2">
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
   <tr data-section="item-3">
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ну вот тоже самое, при второй попытке нажать - ни ссылка старая с адресной строки не убирается, ни скрипт не работает. И выдаёт Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Comment: кликаю второй раз по ссылке и все ок, все без ошибок

Comment: Да всё отлично поправил у себя ошибку. А есть ли возможность выбранный объект центрировать не в самом верху и по середине. И плавность всё равно не работает. Всё просиходит мгновенно

Comment: @BagajokDota, видимо еще какая-то ошибка раз не плавно, у меня то плавность в примере работает. А по поводу середины, не совсем понятно что Вы имеете ввиду. Варьируйте `pos` как необходимо.

Comment: всё получилось, только непонятно как регулировать pos. Нужно посередине

Comment: @BagajokDota, обновила ответ, добавила вариант прокрутки до середины ячейки (секции)

Comment: у меня значение section.offset().top варьируется от -3000 до 17000. А section.height()/2 = 17. Так что еrо ни прибавлять ни отнимать нету смысла(

Comment: @BagajokDota, `section.height()/2` - это середина ячейки. О какой середине Вы говорите, я не понимаю! Поэтому "И дальше тишина"