# Прокрутка до определенного элемента в таблице элементов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, прокрутка

Недавно я обращался с таким же вопросом и мне ответили [В ЭТОЙ ТЕМЕ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644003/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5#comment916162_644003)! Но ответа оказалось мало и я спрашивал в комментах. И дальше тишина.

1) Проблема в следующем. Вот структура всех нужных объектов

```html
<div id="table1">
<table>
<tr id="name-1" class="line">...</tr>
<tr id="name-2">...</tr>
<tr id="name-3">...</tr>
...
<tr id="name-56">...</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

```css
.line{
 width: 100%;
 height: 25px;
 line-height: 25px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
.line td{
 padding: 5px;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Каждой строке в таблице - соответствует объект со ссылкой:

```html
<a id="point-1" href="name-1">
<a id="point-2" href="name-2">
<a id="point-3" href="name-3">
...
<a id="point-56" href="name-56">
```

Вот сам JS

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

$('a').click(function () {
var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href');
var dir = scroll_el.replace(/#/, ''),
section = $('tr').filter('[id="' + dir + '"]'),
pos = section.offset().top + section.height()/2;
$('html, #table').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 500);
});
```

При ПЕРВОМ клике - срабатывает отлично но уходит не на центр окна а вверх.
При клике данное значение section.offset().top = от -2000 до 17000 в зависимости от местоположения в таблице.

А section.height()/2, которое должно прокрутку элемента остановить посередине окна браузера имеет значение = 17. следовательно сложение тысяч и "17" никак не влияет на работу функции.

2) Второй вопрос в том что при первом клике по `<a>` проходит скролл к объекту И ЕСЛИ ПЕРМЕННУЮ pos НЕ вернуть в значение 0, То следующий клик работает очень не предсказуемо.

Comment: Использую для скролла uikit. Пока проблем на змечал https://getuikit.com/docs/scroll

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, описал структуру объектов которые используются в данном вопросе

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить задачу примерно так

```js
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var _to = e.target.hash,
      row = $(_to);

  if (row.length > 0) {
    $('body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: row.offset().top - ($(window).height() / 2) - (row.height() / 2)
    }, 1000, 'swing')
  }
})
```

```css
.panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.panel li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

table {
  margin-top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#name-10">link 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="#name-15">link 15</a></li>
    <li><a href="#name-20">link 20</a></li>
    <li><a href="#name-25">link 25</a></li>
    <li><a href="#name-30">link 30</a></li>
    <li><a href="#name-35">link 35</a></li>
    <li><a href="#name-40">link 40</a></li>
    <li><a href="#name-45">link 45</a></li>
    <li><a href="#name-50">link 50</a></li>
    <li><a href="#name-55">link 55</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="table1">
  <table>
    <tr id="name-1">
      <td>cell 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-2">
      <td>cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-3">
      <td>cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-4">
      <td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-5">
      <td>cell 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-6">
      <td>cell 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-7">
      <td>cell 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-8">
      <td>cell 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-9">
      <td>cell 9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-10">
      <td>cell 10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-11">
      <td>cell 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-12">
      <td>cell 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-13">
      <td>cell 13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-14">
      <td>cell 14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-15">
      <td>cell 15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-16">
      <td>cell 16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-17">
      <td>cell 17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-18">
      <td>cell 18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-19">
      <td>cell 19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-20">
      <td>cell 20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-21">
      <td>cell 21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-22">
      <td>cell 22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-23">
      <td>cell 23</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-24">
      <td>cell 24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-25">
      <td>cell 25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-26">
      <td>cell 26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-27">
      <td>cell 27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-28">
      <td>cell 28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-29">
      <td>cell 29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-30">
      <td>cell 30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-31">
      <td>cell 31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-32">
      <td>cell 32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-33">
      <td>cell 33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-34">
      <td>cell 34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-35">
      <td>cell 35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-36">
      <td>cell 36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-37">
      <td>cell 37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-38">
      <td>cell 38</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-39">
      <td>cell 39</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-40">
      <td>cell 40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-41">
      <td>cell 41</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-42">
      <td>cell 42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-43">
      <td>cell 43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-44">
      <td>cell 44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-45">
      <td>cell 45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-46">
      <td>cell 46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-47">
      <td>cell 47</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-48">
      <td>cell 48</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-49">
      <td>cell 49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-50">
      <td>cell 50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-51">
      <td>cell 51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-52">
      <td>cell 52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-53">
      <td>cell 53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-54">
      <td>cell 54</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-55">
      <td>cell 55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="name-56">
      <td>cell 56</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Блин вот у вас в примере всё работает как мне нужно. А у меня при нажатии на объект выдает ошибку - ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined. Я так думаю это вероятно означает что row пустой (потому что я убрал проверку). Но как он может быть пустым если я нажимаю на объект, следовательно должен считать #name-№

Comment: Выведите в консоль row перед анимацией и посмотрите, есть ли там что-нибудь. А вообще, лучше выложите реальный пример.

Comment: Вообще как это работает:
При клике в переменную _to мы записываем хеш ссылки, т.е. #name-N и затем ищем DOM элемент с id = _to ($(_to)), после чего уже если такой элемент найден, это осуществляет как раз проверка, то скролим страницу на отступ от верхнего края. Проверьте логику у себя в приложении

Comment: row в консоли row = [Object object] прям в таком виде. А как доходит до проверки row.lenght  - то не проходит. Структура реального проекта слишком запутанная и большая что бы выкладывать её сюда. Я скопировал те части которые отвечают за скроллинг и скинул, но видимо этого не хватает(

Comment: и даже если я достаю ссылку из элемента своим способом var _to = $(this).attr('href'),
                    row = $(_to); Всё равно остается последняя проблема. Мотает он не от верха, а как будто прибавляет прошлую позицию. И даже если вручную чуть проскролить вниз таблицу, то уже результат уедет

Comment: Что содержит _to после присвоения var _to = $(this).attr('href') ??

Comment: _to = #name-№, row = [object Object]. То есть после клика по объекту он забирает значение href у кликнутоrо

Answer (score 0):

> А section.height()/2, которое должно прокрутку элемента остановить посередине окна браузера

нет это никак не середина окна браузера, это середина одной (выбранной вами строки). Зачем это сделано - не понятно. Наверное логичнее было бы считать высоту у #table1

и ещё:

```
$('html, #table').animate({scrollTop: pos}, 500);
```

почему "html, #table" зачем обоих скролировать?! и кто такой #table? может имелся ввиду #table1 ?

Comment: скролить обоих просто ттак во всех примерах. И там да table1. Изменил поиск середины секции и всё заработало. Кроме того, если второй раз нажать но на другой объект, всё перемещается в рандомном порядке

Comment: запятые и точки с запятой надо с умом ставить, а не как попало, ну или отступы почеловечески вставить.

Comment: вместо `section = $('tr').filter('[id="' + dir + '"]')` наверное лучше написать `section = $('#' + dir)`

Comment: да но это одно и тоже и не исправляет бага с местоположением. Тоесть если я промотаю вручную таблицу вниз - pos уже будет иметь совершенно странное значение